# Changing color of a drawn oval

Tags: java, swing, object, awt, java-2d

I create an object called "City"

```
    City city = new City (name, rec, g);
```

The object's constructor looks like this:

```
    public City (String name, Rectangle r, Graphics g){
    this.name = name; 
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g; 
    }
```

By creating this object i also draw an oval on an uploaded picture, and set it's colour to BLUE. Here's how I draw the object:

```
    g = (Graphics2D) window.lblNewLabel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(mouseX, mouseY, 15, 15);
```

I would like to be able to change that colour later, after clicking on the oval itself. 
I try to call this function, but it doesn't work:

```
        public void isClicked(){
    clicked = true;
    this.color = Color.RED;
    this.g.setColor(Color.PINK);

}
```

How to change a colour of an existing object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `getGraphics()` on a component causes a transient graphics Object to be used on the component itself. Any subsequent calls to `repaint` will erase the painting done using that object.

Change the color by overriding the `paintComponent` method. Save the `Color` variable as a class member variable and use it to determine the oval color in the method.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.setColor(savedColor);
   g.fillOval(mouseX, mouseY, 15, 15);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `getGraphics()` to do painting, that painting is only temporary and will be lost the next time Swing determines a components needs to be repainted.

Check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for other ideas on doing painting.

You could use a `ShapeIcon` which allows you to change the color of the icon. The icon could be painted in the paintComponent() method of your label.

Or you could use `ShapeComponent` which uses a ShapeIcon. Then you can just add the component to the label like any other component.

> I would like to be able to change that colour later, after clicking on the oval itself

The ShapeIcon would be added to a JLabel. Then you can just add a MouseListener to the label of the ShapeComponent to change the color of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

When you have drawn objects with a `Graphics` object, they are then rendered on the screen. You can't change the color of them directly, instead you will have to repaint your graphics any time when you want to change them. If you want to keep track of the colors for the objects, you will have to store the data in some kind of variable and use it when drawing.